# How to package modules with admin back-end

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x

Say I want to take `mod_custom` as a base for a future module. This module has an admin back-end and is not provided as package.

After modifications, how can I package it for installation? Seems there is no documentation, in Joomla! website, about how to package modules with an admin back-end.

How to organize folders. [Should I copy `Components` structure](https://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions#Accessing_a_Joomla.C7.83_Component)?

How to trigger registration of the admin back-end part?

- Should I mention the admin part in the main xml file like with `Components`?
- Or [should I write a script](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J4.x:Creating_a_Simple_Module#Use_Install.2C_Update_and_Uninstall_script_-_Part_4)?

---

## Update

Moreover, if I only copy/paste my module inside folders, I get "not blocking exception" named `Joomla\CMS\Categories\SectionNotFoundException:` stating that the `$path` does not exists in `./components/com_mod_xxxxx/helpers/category.php`

So seems that a step, that occurs in the installation process, is missing.

Comment: Are you referring to a module or component? Your question starts off talking about a module, but then goes on to reference a component. Perhaps you're referring to bundling up a component **and** module in a single package?

Comment: Well, it is tricky. `mod_custom` is a module, related to `com_content`, but seems, in regard to its composition, to be somehow hybrid. Indeed, it has an admin back-end. Only component are "presented", in the **Joomla! doc** with an admin back-end. But what should I do if I want to take `mod_custom` as a base, and then package it? Should I do as if it was a component? Or as if it was a module?

Comment: At first it seems you want to https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/custom-module-backend/ but then you call it a hybrid -- it is Unclear how it is a hybrid extension.

Comment: @mickmackusa :D Thanks!!! Can you provide your comment as Answer, **AS IT IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED!**

Comment: @JDoe - Only thing I can really conclude is an administrator module. Other than that and I'm still confused. But glad you've found what you want now

Comment: @Lodder, __you right__, but I did not find any mention **in the Joolma!** doc of how to write administrator module, so **I made a wrong assumption**.

Comment: In your XML file, you simply need to replace `client="site"` with `client="administrator"` ;)

Comment: @Lodder, you right, could be summarized like this. I finally find mention on the website, but through search engines… Anyway, I still have the issue related to `Joomla\CMS\Categories\SectionNotFoundException`, stating that the `$path does not exists in ./components/com_mod_xxxxx/helpers/category.php`

Comment: For context, please post all of the files (including paths) for your extension.  With these specifics, volunteers can tailor an answer that is accurate for your scenario.